# Django get() query not working

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, django-queryset

```
this_category = Category.objects.get(name=cat_name)
```

gives error: `get() takes exactly 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)`

I am using the appengine helper, so maybe that is causing problems. Category is my model. `Category.objects.all()` works fine. Filter is also similarily not working.

Thanks,

Comment: Django models don't worko n App Engine with the patch or helper. How are you doing this? Can you include your model's source?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any functions named `name` or `cat_name`? If so, try changing them or the variable names you are using and trying again.

Comment: no, no functions named name or cate_name if I change it to id=1 inside the parentheses it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The helper maps the Django model manager (`Category.objects` in this case) back to the class instance of the model via the `appengine_django.models.ModelManager`.  Through the inheritance chain you eventually come to `appengine.ext.db.Model.get(cls, keys, **kwargs)` so that is why you are seeing this error.  The helper does not support the same interface for `get` that Django does.  If you do not want to `get` by primary key, you must use a filter

To do your query, you need to use the GAE filter function like this:

```
this_category = Category.objects.all().filter('name =', cat_name).get()
```